# Where to Define supporting methods of Service Class in NestJS

Tags: function, nestjs, structure, directory-structure

In NestJS, I have created one module named as Example, in this module I have defined

```
--example.controller.ts 
--example.module.ts
--exmaple.service.ts
```

In `exmaple.controller.ts`, I have created one POST Endpoint

```
@Post()
@HttpCode(201)
async create(@Body() book: Book){
    this.exampleService.create(book);
}
```

and corresponding Service method is defined in exmaple.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ExampleService {
    private readonly books: Book[] = [];

    create(book: Book) {
       // call 10 supporting different functions to get the data from third party API
    }

}
```

Now suppose there are 10 different supporting methods needs to be called before returning any data from service to Controller.

Where should we define these 10 functions ? suppose out of these 10 functions there are 5 pairs, which means that each 2 functions are inter-related and 5 pairs are getting formed for these 10 functions.

So shall we create 5 classes and define those pair of functions in each class and call them from Service method Create ?

Can any one guide me with folder structure I should follow

Answer (score 0):

No need to do that unless the main datatable is changed. You can write the required 10 function and call them in your main function using this.fun_name;
But if you want to create each function for each service then there will be thousands of services which is trouble.